# jQuery Click Event Issue - Framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-framework-7

So I have a couple of problems. The first one... I have 2 pages, a `products.html` page and a `search.html` page. The `products.html` page runs some Ajax in the .onPageAfterAnimation(); to get the products from the database and display them. The returned HTML contains a part where the user can increase and decrease a number value inside a textbox.

[image: The button to]

The button to increase or decrease the value by 1 initially works when I open the `products.html` page, however, when I go into the `search.html` and go back to the `products.html` page using my Android's back button (I have `pushState = true`) and press the increase/decrease button it increases/decreases by 2. If I try to do the same thing again it increases/decreases by 3 and so on…

[image: This is my inc]

This is my increase/decrease code in my products.html page:

```
myApp.onPageAfterAnimation('catalogs', function (page) {

  //Increse/decrease product quantity
  $(“.promo-screen-content”).on(“click”, “.addToCartBtn”, function(){
    var productid = $(this).attr(“data-productId”),
        currentvalue = parseInt($('#txtQuantity' + productid).val());

    $('#txtQuantity' + productid).val((currentvalue + 1).toString());
  });

  $(“.promo-screen-content”).on(“click”, “.removeFromCartBtn”, function(){
    var productid = $(this).attr(“data-productId”),
        currentvalue = parseInt($('#txtQuantity' + productid).val());

    if(currentvalue > 1){
        $('#txtQuantity' + productid).val((current_value – 1).toString());
    }
  });

});
```

Anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

My second problem is a little bit different. When ever I click a button it takes that click and performs the process 3 or 4 times. So, for example, if I show a notification when it is clicked it shows that notification 3 or 4 times.

I don't know if these are common or know issues that people have came across. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When are you calling the above code ? (*when does the binding occur*). I am asking because the problem is that you have the same handlers bound multiple times (*so they run multiple times*).

Comment: So a quick fix might be to use `off` to unbind the handlers before binging again. `$(“.promo-screen-content”).off('click','.addToCartBtn').on(“click”,'.addToCartBtn', ...)` and `$(“.promo-screen-content”).off('click','.removeFromCartBtn').on(“click”,'.removeFromCartBtn', ...)`. But there must be a more correct way based on the **Framework7** which i am not using so i cannot suggest anything relevant.

Comment: By default all the pages are loaded in using Ajax. I don't know if that might have something to do with it because when I go to `search.html` then back to `products.html` then refresh in that page it start working again. So this happens after a second page is loaded with Ajax and go back.

Comment: I'm running this code inside `myApp.onPageAfterAnimation();`.

Comment: I just tried your  `.off()` recommendation and it worked, thanks a lot! I have never heard of this method, can you please explain how it works in an answer so I can mark this question as Answered? @GabyakaG.Petrioli

Comment: `off()` is a band-aid solution - you should not be assigning these event handlers more than once on a page.  I would think `$(document).ready` would be a more suitable place for the handlers.

Comment: The `myApp.onPageAfterAnimation();` is inside the `$(document).ready();`. So it looks something like this: `$(document).ready(function(){ myApp.onPageAfterAnimation(function(){ //All my code in here }); });`

Comment: @BrianMoreno from the docs (https://framework7.io/docs/page-callbacks.html#callbacks-methods) it looks like the `onPageInit` event might be a better candidate to use.

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I didn't try this before. Thanks it's working inside `.onPageInit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was putting my code inside the wrong page callback. I had to put it inside the `.onPageInit();` callback.